# Why does this for loop stop before reaching the intended value?

Tags: php, loops, for-loop

```
for($i=0;$i<=2;$i+=0.1){
    echo  $i."<br>";
}
```

The result I wish is:

```
0
0.1
0.2
0.3
0.4
0.5
0.6
0.7
0.8
0.9
1
1.1
1.2
1.3
1.4
1.5
1.6
1.7
1.8
1.9
2
```

What happens instead is the loop reaches `1.9` and stops.  Why?

Comment: @Brad, thanks for cleaning that up. You made this question a lot more readable and salvageable. +1 to the question! Perhaps we should all more closely look at a question before voting it down, as we definitely have the power to turn it around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't work due to floating point precision. The numbers are stored in base 2 format and are never exact due to rounding. When you add .1 to 1.9, you don't end up with 2.0. You end up with something like 1.99999. On the next iteration you would end up with something like 2.099998 depending on what it rounds to in base 2 format.

For more information see [Floating point numbers](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php) and 
[Double-precision floating-point format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format)

You could also do something like this to get the result you are after

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 2.1; $i += .1){
    echo  $i . '<br />';
}
```

Comment: the question was "why doesn't it work", so some explanation about floating points in addition to the code would have got you up-votes.

Answer (score 5):

Because, it will never achieve `floating point` == `integer`

Comment: +1 Exactly. If you want this to work you need to check if == 2.0

Answer (score 0):

You can do by:

```
for($i=0;$i<=20;$i+=1){
    echo  ($i/10)."<br>";
}
```